# What is happening to my baking?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking

I modelled kind of a soft cube, similar to a foam/cubic pillow/"cloth".
The High Poly mesh was done using cloth simulation.
[image]

Now I'm trying to bake this mesh to a low poly on. Actually to a basic cube.

[image]

But once I bake this (diffuse, combined) the bake has some issues that looks like the normal of some polygons are inverted, but they aren't.

[image]

In the bake looks like there is another mesh on top of the original one, in the same object, but it hasn't. You can see some areas with strange tones, that looks like another mesh was on top of the original one in some areas. You can see it specially in the third and fourth big blocks [from left to right] of the image above.

I tried all that I could to flip and correct the outside and inside of the mesh. I also tried exporting as fbx, glb and importing on blender again and baking again. The result is always the same. I also tried using cages.

I also tried sculpting and baking afterwards, but the result was the same!

What can it be? How can I bake this "soft" high poly block to a basic 6 faces polygon (low poly) ?

Here is the .blend file:
[image]

Comment: Upload it at https://blend-exchange.com and follow instructions there. After uploading you get an html text which you copy completely and paste it into your question.

Comment: Can you see the different tones in the blue? And I'm not talking about that really visible issue in the first cube (left to right) in the UV image.
I'm talking about the strange issues that are most visible on the 3rd and 4th (left to right) cubes in the UV maps. Looks like some parts are showing the inside of the mesh or something. The second plane in the UV map is the only one face that baked correct in this baking process. All others have issues.

Comment: I'm no expert in baking textures, I never do this except for a few tests. I just wanted to help you upload the file. But now that you ask, doesn't the combined bake also take lighting into account? To me the different colors look like they are just lit differently, as I would expect with one side getting full light and the others less, and the bottom part the least.

Comment: Not really, I've seem this kind of issue, when rendering objects and the objects had some parts of the mesh coming inside of others. It is looking the same, but it is not the case.